# how to create two columns from one column in R?

Tags: r

| outcome |
| --- |
| Death |
| Death |
| NA |

i used this to above table :
input_data2 %>% mutate(outcome,Death = ifelse(outcome == "Death", 1, 0),
recover = ifelse(outcome == "Recover", 1, 0)) %>%
input_data2

then i get this:

| Death | Recover |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 |
| NA | NA |

next if i type :  input_data2
it comes to normal :

| outcome |
| --- |
| Death |
| Death |
| NA |

what my desired output is the following:

| Death | Recover |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 |
| NA | NA |

i'm new to 'R', please kindly help me..

Comment: Hello, you are on the right track, you just need to assign the result of your command to a new object, or (but this is not necessarily good practice) to `input_data2`. Your command will look like `input_data3 <- input_data2 %>% mutate(outcome,Death = ifelse(outcome == "Death", 1, 0), recover = ifelse(outcome == "Recover", 1, 0))` (so without the last "piping").

Comment: Also, this would work, but I don't like it: `input_data2 %>% mutate(outcome,Death = ifelse(outcome == "Death", 1, 0), recover = ifelse(outcome == "Recover", 1, 0)) -> input_data3`.